# How to sort a text file with awk?

Tags: perl, awk, text-processing

I would like to reorder a whole file.

file.txt looks like this:

```
1 10
1 10
2 10
1 11
2 11
2 10
```

I would like it to look like this:

```
1 10
1 10
1 11
2 10
2 11
2 10
```

Comment: why don't you use `sort` command in bash ?

Answer (score 2):

This will maintain the order of the lines within each grouping:

```
perl -ane '
    push @{$lines{$F[0]}}, $_;
   } {
    print join "", map {join "", @{$lines{$_}}} sort keys %lines;
' <<END
1 a
2 a
1 b
1 a
2 c
2 b
END
```

```
1 a
1 b
1 a
2 a
2 c
2 b
```

Answer (score 1):

`sort -k1,2 file.txt`

produces

```
1 10
1 10
1 11
2 10
2 10
2 11
```

Comment: row 5 must be: 2 11 and row 6 must be: 2 10

Comment: @HamedGhadimi `sort -k1n -s file.txt`

Comment: @HamedGhadimi - I don't understand why "2 11" should be before "2 10"

Comment: @JoseRicardoBustosM. Thank you it works.

Comment: @ChrisKoknat This seems to be an indexed series. So the point is to take all `1` entries *in the order they are now* first, then all `2` entries, *in the order they are now* next...

Answer (score 1):

For this is better to use `sort` command

```
sort -k1n -s file.txt
```

Another solution using `Gnu-awk` 4, [Controlling Scanning](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Controlling-Scanning.html)

```
gawk '
{d[$1][length(d[$1])+1]=$0}
END{
    PROCINFO["sorted_in"] = "@val_num_asc"; 
    for(key in d){
        for(i=1; i<=length(d[key]); ++i) {
            print d[key][i]
        }
    }
}' file.txt
```

you get,

```
1 10
1 10
1 11
2 10
2 11
2 10
```